# Draggable QLabels in pyqt5

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pyqt5, qt-designer, qlabel

I'm working with pyqt5 and qt designer in python 3.7.x and my draggable QLabels don't seems to work. I'm trying to set de Labels as draggable and drop them into another Label, but my code doesn't work, I made the window in qt designer and also defined the Lebels there, but when I try to "transform" the QLabels into a draggable objects nothing happens. Here is some of my code and I'll explain:

```
class Window(window_name, base_class):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.penguin_list = (
            self.cyan,
            self.red,
            self.yellow,
            self.purple,
            self.green
        )  # This tuple is made out of the QLabel created on qt designer that i want to drag 

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        # Here I tried to set the QLabel that I want to drag (the one the mouse pressed)
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            for penguin in self.penguin_list:
                if penguin.underMouse():
                    self.penguin = penguin
                    self.drag_start_position = event.pos() 

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        # Here is when I tried to convert the QLavel into draggable
        # Also the QLabel appears in the top left corner (sometimes) with a white background
        # And also the drop part doesn't work and I can not drop the QLabel
        if not (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton):
            return
        if (event.pos() - self.drag_start_position).manhattanLength() < QApplication.startDragDistance():
            return

        drag = QDrag(self.penguin)
        mimedata = QMimeData()
        mimedata.setImageData(self.penguin.pixmap())

        drag.setMimeData(mimedata)
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.penguin.size())
        painter = QPainter(pixmap)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.penguin.rect(), self.penguin.grab())
        painter.end()
        drag.setPixmap(pixmap)
        drag.setHotSpot(event.pos())
        drag.exec_(Qt.CopyAction | Qt.MoveAction)
```

Overall I wanna make a copy of the QLabel when i click on it and drop it (pasted) in other QLabel that is in other QFrame.

Comment: Assuming you are using a QWidget and not a QMainWindow, your code works (as long you avoid `setHotSpot()`, for which you're using the wrong coordinate reference). Also, where is "the drop part" that "doesn't work"? There's no trace of it in your code.

Comment: But I'm using QMainWindow, why wouldn't it work? @musicamante

Comment: QMainWindow is a special type of QWidget and handles mouse events in different ways. What system are you on?

Comment: Windows 10 if that's what u mean

Comment: Please edit the question and add the ui file (or the pyuic generated file).